# SQL wildcard contains the word and not as part of another word

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

I have to write aql query with condition where word contains the word 'kg' and **not as part of another word**.

I have tried:

```
WHERE word LIKE '% kg %' or word LIKE 'kg %' or word LIKE '% kg' or word LIKE 'kg'
```

Is there another way shorter than that?

Comment: This might be tricky. For example  `He weights 80kg.` or `10 kg, 15 kg`

Answer (score 1):

You can add delimiters in.  Using standard SQL constructs:

```
WHERE ' ' || word || ' ' LIKE '% kg %'
```

Not all databases support the standard concatenation operator.  Use the appropriate function in your database.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to consider cases like 100kg then I would only exclude when there is an alpha immediately before or after "kg".

```
WHERE word LIKE '%KG%' AND word NOT LIKE '%[A-Z]KG[A-Z]%'
```